# efficient way to manually check if user is logged in or not in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I am working on a asp.net 3.5 application where asp.net membership is not implemented.  If a user logs into the application, i am maintaining a flag in the users table which will be set true if the user is logged in and is set to false if the user manually logs out or if the user is idle for more than 5 minutes.  If this flag's value is true, other users cannot login into the application using the same user name.

I am using `Session_End` event of Global.asax file set the flag value as false when the user is idle for more than 5 minutes, but the problem is that sometimes the flag value is not getting updated to false if the user idles for more than 5 minutes which shows that Session_End is not very reliable.

Someone please suggest me an alternative to `Session_End` for the above scenario.

Comment: `Session_End` will definitely fire at the end of a session if running in `InProc` mode - it doesn't happen arbitrarily and intermittently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use Session timeout to forcibly end session.  More info can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Did you set any timeout value?

Comment: yes the timeout is set to 5 minutes and as far as i know this 5 minutes is the idle time i.e, if the user continuously uses the website for say 15 minutes and idles for 5 minutes then only his session will expire am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, session will expire only after 5min idle period.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timespan mechanism.  Refresh the timespan on every user action on the server.  When timespan is older than 5 minutes, you'll know he is gone.

Comment: This is what the Session mechanism will do for you, reliably.

Comment: I thought the problem was about an unreliable session mechanism, so proposed an alternative to it...

Comment: the timeout in my case is set to 5 minutes which means if the user uses the website for 10 mins and idles for 5 mins his session will expire is this correct?...also i am storing userid in a session variable when the user logs and some times this value becomes null and it not available when session end fires which is the main problem i am facing..i cant user timespan here as user can spend more than 5 minutes before logging out..